# Chrome 31, ondragover event does not give me dataTransfer.type

Tags: google-chrome, drag-and-drop, fileapi

I've run into the File API update where we no longer get the details about the item being dragged until drop, and I've read a number of answers here on SO and elsewhere saying that you can still access the type via `event.dataTransfer.type(s)`. This is not the case for me. Firefox gives me the `types` property, but Chrome gives nothing. Has anyone else dealt with this?

Edit: To be clear, in Chrome, the `type` property does exist, but it's value is `null`